# Is it possible to perform a run-time type check to determine if a property is a function with a specific call signature and return type?

Tags: typescript

I am new user learning Typescript. Is it possible, to perform a run-time type check to determine if a property is a function with a specific call signature and return type?

```js
function isCourseAction(action: any): action is CourseAction {
  const FunctionType = 'function';

  try {
    // check expected properties defined and of expected type
    if (!action.success && typeof action.success !== FunctionType) {
      return false;
    } else if (!action.request && typeof action.request !== FunctionType) {
      return false;
    } else if (!action.failure && typeof action.failure !== FunctionType) {
      return false;
    }

    // other than try and call the request, success and failure function here
    // and catch exception is there a quicker way to check that the function has
    // the expected call signature?
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Created a typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=55&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEwIIGNgEtkB2UAvFAN4BQUUcO+BAKuBAFxQDOwATrgQOYAaKjTqF4SVGjace-IQF8KFUJCgBhZAFcu7CNjyES5Ye01YsEduzYAKOFz4BGad16CaDgEwvZfAJQkAHywCCjo+vRC1ABmcLiI2qxQdg7OHK5yHnze6b4BxMHiYZiiBFFQXBAAjpqWwLb2Tj5uAlk5Mm75haGSEYQKSliEnFAAtiAa2rp9BGyTOnqlRpTUpuaW1slgPejN-H5sRb1LBcbU1EME7MiIEAB0KHw2AAZrFlZQWHCIt2hQAO64YAACygABIyNsJOh5M8-ABuYTUSrAbREMi0AyMZhsADkAGUAKpqNQAUXx+IA+hg1AwAJIAeQAcrjWpj6EddlAocV5IjqPJyrF4olbDzJHt-IcdiUsUEzudLtdbg9kE9nsKEpVPt9fgCgaCIeKYXD+ecUWjyCIsUxIHiAGIYOkAGUJACVSdTaYyWWzSpypNyZXzhILhJUanUxTLJQcQtDZfR5StFcMbvdHi8I7URl8fhA-oCQVl2ODIcHTUiKhBUVx0db6LakriPQBFQnkhhe+nM1kNsQxoMJqAhgUURRK4BQAjIYA0rQLGbLYSa0XJOMETSjABGEC4yarFrrUAADGbFIoKEr06r1WpdW5q5GRqcIeN5tNSnds3UbLjGo4fb-l4uJ+LCCJXmmKqZs894-I+bwbPKb4TAun5YnciFWH+AFAY0nigeBiLXtBaovHBiCPqu2qvmQ75oYsGHURAOGpHhIFgZWkFXDeMG4OwH6MfQNj0VMQmEF0Zb8YJMwiahYkzJxEEkRmZHPNJDEzHC3HKqp6oaQppQ2DOc4yaUkkQgZi5GSZ86GViSmIhQ0SaAQSxWehwnsoQbBwAQIBxt5RD8eomlLCmk5QParmlE2Ri4i5blYriTnUAA9GlnzAhAWAANZQBAAAekA4AW3JcMgkBcHglhQGgEDRLwZV+X8yDRAVxU5cAZUqBAwi4O1NgAIRBZhZjvKWABkk1QL1bX9gQY3rB8Q3EKQ0VJY2zABCmyI1pasSILo54FUd0ADckI1fj+IzTbNzDzaNN1Tqt60xTa20KnttZEIdx2hqduhQBdw2jcxUB3XN7Vg3EWrQK9UXvVtkA7Ye+3Hn9EDnsIEBnV91Y-bNXC1Nj45AA)

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be a [mcve], since `CourseAction` is not defined anywhere, and `(!action.success && typeof action.success !== "function")` seems like a weird test, since if `action.success` is falsy then `typeof action.success` will definitely not be `"function"` (there are no falsy functions in JavaScript) and you don't need to test it.

Comment: You can't tell at runtime if a function matches a TS signature. You can check `fn.length` to get the number of arguments the function expects in JavaScript, but even this is [brittle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxnCZgEMBGAbCAxAdlAXigAoAPALigGdgAnAS1wHMBKQgPmrsaYG4oAUHAD2uGlGEBrFCErxEydFjyEopDmt5DRVYVgB0GYU2JSZhiM2AALFvwD09qAEZtY4F3oYMAeWmzYBCRUTBx8ImJ9KJRaJio2Ak4YuIBtAAYAXS0RMT0IQ2NiGi9ffwsrWwcnNLdxYu8AZWASvxk5IMVQlQiKLgZmABooEAB+SlwAVwBbNAhaBM5SWryCk3qMJpayrAq7KEcoACZBIA), so I wouldn't try. You'll need some heuristic I guess, but I need an [mcve] to properly advise.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz have added link to typescript playground

Comment: Okay, at the very least you should properly test for `"function"`, which you're not doing, see `console.log(isCourseAction({ success: "oops", request: "oops", failure: "oops" })); // true`.  But that's really just an error in your [mcve] and not an answer to the question, so can you fix that first? (maybe change `&&` to `||`?)

Comment: Cheers @jcalz, updated....

Comment: Can you explain a little about why you need to test the function at runtime as opposed to just requiring the function conform at design time?  Is your emitted TS code going to be called as a pure JS library or are the library users going to use TS as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't tell at runtime if a function matches a TS signature.  I'll use your example function signature, which looks like this:

```
type ActionCallback = (arg1: string, arg2: string) => PayloadAction;
```

As you know, you can check if a value `fn` is a function at all with a simple `typeof` check.  After that you quickly run out of reasonable options.  You can *try* to check `fn.length` to get the number of arguments the function expects in JavaScript, but this is brittle:

```
const normal: ActionCallback = (x, y) => ({ actionType: x, actionPayload: y });
console.log(normal.length); // 2
const fewer: ActionCallback = (x) => normal(x, x);
console.log(fewer.length); // 1
const evenFewer: ActionCallback = (...[x, y]) => normal(x, y);
console.log(evenFewer.length); // 0
const more: ActionCallback = (x: string, y: string, z?: string) => normal(x, z ? z : y);
console.log(more.length); // 3
```

All of those functions meet the `ActionCallback` contract but they have different `length` properties at runtime.

---

Obviously, as you hinted, you could go ahead and *call* the function on some test inputs and use the result as a guide toward verifying your function, like this:

```
function testFunc(x: any): x is (a: string, b: string) => PayloadAction {
  if (typeof x !== "function") return false;
  const ret = x("", ""); // actually call function
  return typeof ret.actionType === "string" && typeof ret.actionPayload === "string";
}

function isCourseAction(action: any): action is CourseAction {
  return (["success", "request", "failure"].every(k => testFunc(action[k])));
}
```

And this will sort of work... although even this is not perfect; a particularly bizarre function could happen to return something reasonable for the test inputs but something entirely different for other inputs:

```
function ohComeOn(x: string, y: string) {
  if (!x && !y) return { actionType: "normal", actionPayload: "all perfectly normal" };
  return 12345;
}
const why = { success: ohComeOn, request: ohComeOn, failure: ohComeOn }
console.log(isCourseAction(why)); // true
console.log(why.request("other", "input")); // 12345, not a PayloadAction at all!
```

In practice I wouldn't worry about this exception much (I mean, someone could hand you a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) specifically crafted to pass your tests but fail when you use it).  But if you don't want to call the function to test it, you might be out of luck.

---

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEwIIGNgEtkB2UAvFAN4BQUUcO+BAKuBAFxQDOwATrgQOYAaKjTqF4SVGjace-IQF8KFUJCgBhZAFcu7CNjyES5Ye01YsEduzYAKOFz4BGad16CaDgEwvZfAJQkAHywCCjo+vRC1ABmcLiI2qxQdg7OHK5yHnze6b4BxMHiYZiiBFFQXBAAjpqWwLb2Tj5uAlk5Mm75haGSEYQKSsrMUH0EanCIiABGtADWRilNuS1tzfxdIRLhpQDcFFiEnFAEyFwAthNso+OTM1jzpDYAHq0gGzZkIgaMzGwvX-QipI2CAoPI-HsDgR2MhEBAAHQoPg2E7nCaIiD8YAACwhUAA9PioJ59odgFBohAAO4QLhXUo3aZzBZPDaoi6IZ6tVmQw6whFImyUmlcDFY3E7AlExyk6HkiAAN0xADFqbT6d9GXcHsl4XqANr-EAAXTZpw5XKgb150P5iOQyMVKrVorh4rxhKgAAZZUczqcktcJkz7iy1u4QOHWgAvAD84bNaM5-2jUFjUFTIIhvrtgv9lTFfBxHqJAGZBtFNARSlBgHVlVWsM82HACG8-lBcOxknAo1ApgmgptiqNjNRcNFkioIMhJ08oABCYikABEler3xXAUqwG0RFiiF0e2oUKOO6MTxsK5XrWvJa+mmDoKwwYpje+wh3e9rzFnFQgwDwrQ3xMKoy6rh0-ArlAABkME-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-sJRy64Tr3vZP9ArQna0M40jjdw-XgM34lfzTnyKH8Gx8o1VQ4L5vQnqMeE-8rA2Bfk4Z+jRPBvw-vDL+B8j78C6irSogCyCXxAaUeEM9KiQMfjA1+79yZ7E-vvRGY0yLX0IDYbBNDRgbEJtQiapR6HAMYaUUh2ZEGUNYT9eg5MKFIwEbQyyZ1x5cO+MwsgYiKKSKvkwj+QA)

Comment: Many thanks @jcalz for your help and examples, appreciated :) Ok, so it looks like the best hope is to test for typeof function and maybe call the function with test inputs....

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in type `Function` and define a type guard like this :

```
function isFunction(p: any): p is Function{
  return typeof p === "function"  
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/G4QwTgBAjhC8EDMCuA7AxgFwJYHsUQAoBKCAbwChyBfS0SABzggCJmBuS5dbPCLAZwBiqTLhQF6ALgggUATyLTGAiMO5iy5CBDABTDEjD4Mc+rpwIIjWDZZdReZtUpZLBAWofioREhW1oePw4ADa6AHQhOADmBMxYALYgiCI8KMxEHDTkroQeqWISvpoBQaERUbHxSSnqeAD8GVlAA)

Comment: Thanks @Eldar, is it possible to perform a check that the function has a specific set of arguments and return type?

Comment: Its not possible until u will add such properties to it, Function is an object, so you can workaround that

Comment: @anon_dcs3spp You can extract return type with `ReturnType<typeof p>` and parameters type with `Parameters<typeof p>` but I'm not sure you can use them as typeguards.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects also, so as objects functions have properties and methods (apply, bind). One of these properties is - `name`, for named functions it will be a string with a function name, for anonymous it will be empty string.

If you will pass functions which were named then this property can be used to distinguish specific function in the runtime. Consider:

```
// two named functions as an example
const f1 = (arg1: string) => {
    // body
}
const f2 = (arg1: number) => {
    // body
}

function main(obj: {name: string, payload: Function | string}) {
    if (typeof obj.payload === 'function' && obj.payload.name === 'f1') {
        // it is f1 function 
    }
    if (typeof obj.payload === 'function' && obj.payload.name === 'f2') {
        // it is f2 function 
    }
}
```

We can also be more safe on the type level by type guards and type specification:

```
const f1 = (arg1: string) => {
    // body
}
const f2 = (arg1: number) => {
    // body
}

const isF1 = (a: unknown): a is typeof f1 => typeof a === 'function' && a.name === 'f1'; 
const isF2 = (a: unknown): a is typeof f2 => typeof a === 'function' && a.name === 'f2'; 

function main(obj: {name: string, payload: typeof f1 | typeof f2 | string}) {
    if (isF1(obj.payload)) {
        obj.payload // it is f1 on type level also
    }
    if (isF2(obj.payload)) {
        obj.payload // it is f2 on type level also
    }
}
```